# How to get the semver Major part of a Maven version?

Tags: maven, semantic-versioning

Is it possible to get the major version (`<Major>.<Minor>.<Patch>`) of the `project.version`?

For example if my version is `1.3.4`, I'd like to get `1` to later use it in a configuration of the same pom.xml

Something like:

```
<configuration>
  <name>project_name.${project.version:major}</name>
</configuration>
```

If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: It is worth noting that Maven does not use the http://SemVer.org versioning specification. It instead uses it's own convention which is very similar. Read about it here (under the 3.3.1 "Project Versions" section)... http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Found it. The [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) has the ability to parse-out the components of the version.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <id>parse-version</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>parse-version</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <echo>[version] ${project.version}</echo>
                <echo>[majorVersion] ${parsedVersion.majorVersion}</echo>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: +1 - I have been using Maven for years and yet did not know about this!

Answer (score 13):

This works on Maven 3.3.9:

```
${project.artifact.selectedVersion.majorVersion}
```

Comment: That worked very well for me in maven 3.3.9. Any idea if that's a standard maven thing? I couldn't find the official maven documentation for that variable

Comment: I can say that `${project.artifact}` is a nice trick, but not a standard. Officially, only `${project}`, see https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Comment: @MarcosZolnowski, incorrect, the API is the official documentation: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getArtifact()

Comment: That API is for plugin developers, there is no guarantee for maven users. Anytime they can change this behavior.

Comment: That is not the plugin api, that is core api. The plugin api specification is: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-plugin-api/apidocs/index.html

Comment: There is the API to make plugins, and the API to access Maven internals. Both are to be used by plugin developers. I still can't recommend that users access internals expecting this to always work. Look at the documentation you sent, there is no explanation there about this feature. Just a javadoc that says `method getSelectedVersion`. What it really does? Get the selected version of what?

Answer (score 1):

Versions don't necessarily come in the structure you describe.

Maven has conventions for trailing numbers, but you don't have to use them.

If you have a convention that you like that you want to disassemble, you can write your own maven plugin that sets several properties to the several pieces as you define them.

Comment: According to [the Maven reference documentation](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html) from Sonatype there is a convention (which you are free to violate).